# Find the isomorphism class of subgroup of order 16 in $U(105)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

According to Sylow's 1st theorem, the multiplicative group $U(105)$ of order $\phi(105)=48=2^4\cdot 3$ must have a subgroup, say $H$ of order $2^4$. I was wondering what could be the isomorphism class of $H$.

First of all, $H$ cannot be of the form $U_d(n)$ for any positive divisor $d$ of 105 because if so, then the subgroup $U_d(105)$ of order 16 will isomorphic to $U(105/d)$ where $(105, 105/d)=1$. Now $d\in \{1,3,5,7,15,21,35,105\}$ and none of them satisfies the above criterion.

Now let us check other possibilities. If $H$ is of order 16, then being subgroup of an abelian group, $H$ is also abelian. In this case by the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups we see $H$ is isomorphic to any one of the following
$$\mathbb{Z}_{16},\\ \mathbb{Z}_8\times \mathbb{Z}_2, \\ \mathbb{Z}_4^2, \\ \mathbb{Z}_4\times \mathbb{Z}_2^2, \\ \mathbb{Z}_2^4$$
Clearly $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$ is rejected case because if not, then $H$ is cyclic. Then it will have a generator say $\alpha$ of order 16. Also 3 is prime divisor of $105=|U(105)|$ so by Cauchy's theorem the group $U(105)$ will have an element $\beta$ of order 3. Since $\alpha, \beta$ commute and their orders are relatively prime, so $|\alpha\beta|=|\alpha||\beta|=16\cdot 3=48=|U(105)|$ making $U(105)$ a cyclic group, contradiction since $U(n)$ is cyclic iff $n\in \{2,4,p^m, 2p^m\}$ where $p$ is odd prime.

But what now? How to decide the isomorphism class? Am I missing anything? Please suggest me the answer in elementary way as only Sylow's 1st theorem I have studied and I am willing to solve this problem no other sylow's theorem if possible ( however basic group properties, external direct product etc we can use).

Any help please ? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I got the following on my own. Can you please tell me if this correct.
Since $U(105)=U(3\times 5\times 7)\simeq U(3)\times U(5)\times U(7)\simeq \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_4\times \mathbb{Z}_6\simeq \mathbb{Z}_2^2\times \mathbb{Z}_4\times \mathbb{Z}_3$, therefore any subgroup of order 16 of $U(105)$ will isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_4$ only.

Comment: Your edit is correct! Just to check your understanding: why is $U(3 \times 5 \times 7) \simeq U(3) \times U(5) \times U(7)$?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk I studied Gallian, in which it was given that, $U(mn)\simeq U(m)\times U(n)$ iff $(m,n)=1$. Here is the extension to three factors, that's why.

Comment: Fair enough :) If you're curious about why this is true, look up the Chinese Remainder Theorem.